# Is there a compact name mangling usable for file name generation?

Tags: filenames, name-mangling

I have a project where I am wanting to generate code similar to C++ templates, but I want to generate each instance into a separate file. Using the C++ standard name mangling system, I keep running into the 255 character limit for path length. I am wondering if anyone knows of a particularly compact name mangling scheme for types so I can avoid the work of generating one of my own.

To put it another way: C++ name mangling maps each type to a unique name. I wanted to use those unique names as file names. But those names are commonly too long for file names. I could try to do some sort of bit-packing on the different characters used in the C++ name mangling, but my first attempt generated names that used characters that are illegal in file names and, I later realized, wasn't actually guaranteed to provide unique names.

Trying to hash the resulting mangled name raises the specter of a name collision. I want to avoid that. I'd like something where any given data type yields a unique name, even when I have to include in the name multiple nested anonymous structs or multidimensional array elements.

**My hope was that someone else had run into a similar problem of trying to save files based on data types, whether in C++ OR IN SOME OTHER LANGUAGE, such that I could just borrow their scheme for producing these names.**

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "particularly compact"? Can you give some examples of what you're trying to do and where you run into problems? As it stands, this question doesn't really have enough information for anybody to give a useful answer.

Comment: You can use hash of the mangled name, if you need to limit the path length

Comment: I expanded the question to provide more details.

Comment: Hashing with something like SHA-256 is highly unlikely to cause a name collision anytime before our sun goes dark.

Comment: @GregHewgill Highly unlikely, true, but if there's a truly impossible answer, I'd like to know about it instead. Also, a hash has a chance of generating characters that aren't legal in a file name, meaning I'd have to apply an escape layer over the top. It's not a bad solution, but my question was to find the best solution. A hash is probably what I will fall back to if no one has a better answer.

Comment: @srm If you base64url the hash, it won't contain characters illegal in a file name. I doubt any better answer could arrive because usual name mangling schemes either don't have any limit on the length or hash.